# Applications menu does not find installed eclipse

Tags: 12.04, apt, eclipse, appmenu

I just switched from my company's version of eclipse to the stock Ubuntu version. However, when I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove eclipse
```

I found that my company's eclipse remained installed. I figured it was installed outside the package repo, so I tried:

```
which eclipse
```

which returned

```
/usr/bin/eclipse
```

so I rm-ed it. The shortcut to eclipse remained in my applications menu, but returns a 'failed to launch application' error. Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

which returned success, but

```
which eclipse
```

does not return anything, and attempting to launch eclipse gives the same 'failed to launch application' error as when there was no eclipse installed.

How do I get the ui/package manager to agree on whether/where eclipse is installed? Failing that, how do I figure out what the applications menu is trying to launch, and how do I figure out what the package manager has installed?

EDIT:

More output was requested:

```
locate eclipse | grep bin/
```

gives

```
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/ant
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/ant.bat
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/ant.cmd
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/antRun
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/antRun.bat
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/antRun.pl
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/antenv.cmd
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/complete-ant-cmd.pl
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/envset.cmd
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/lcp.bat
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/runant.pl
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/runant.py
/other/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/bin/runrc.cmd
/usr/bin/eclipse
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/bin/ant
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/bin/ant.cmd
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/bin/antRun
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/bin/antRun.pl
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/bin/antenv.cmd
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/bin/complete-ant-cmd.pl
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/bin/envset.cmd
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/bin/runant.pl
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/bin/runant.py
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/bin/runrc.cmd
```

And

```
find /opt /usr/bin /usr/lib /usr/local/ -iname eclipse -type f
```

gives

```
/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
```

And

```
dpkg -S "bin/eclipse"
```

gives

```
eclipse-platform: /usr/bin/eclipse
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So it should run using just `eclipse` ?

Comment: no, it didn't. I think the locate db wasn't updated, so it reported /usr/bin/eclipse even though it wasn't there. I forget how to update that manually. 

I just tried dpkg --purge eclipse-platform though--after apt-get remove-ing some other things that had eclipse-platform as a dependency, it seems to have worked. Thank you for your help; I wouldn't have tried dpkg without it.

Comment: So does it work ? if so There old eclipse files in `/other/eclipse` , you may won't to remove them.